node and react axios 404
I kept getting 404 error in the console
login.js:25 Server responded with status code: 404 handleSubmit@login.js:25"
the backend works fine itself but with react it keeps giving errors, I already used cors and express.json()
my react code looks like this
try {
  const response = await axios.post(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/users/login",
    { email, password }
  );

  const { token } = response.data;
  localStorage.setItem("token", token);

  console.log("Login Successful");
  // Redirect or navigate to another page upon successful login
} catch (err) {
  if (err.response) {
    console.error(
      "Server responded with status code:",
      err.response.status
    );
    setError("Invalid email or password. Please try again.");
  } else if (err.request) {
    console.error("No response received:", err.request);
    setError("No response received from server");
  } else {
    console.error("Error during request setup:", err.message);
    setError("Error during request setup");
  }
}

my backend code looks like this
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);

router.post("/login", login);

exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });
    }

    const isPasswordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

    if (!isPasswordMatch) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid email or password" });
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_secret, {
      expiresIn: "360000000",
    });

    return res.json({ token });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Tite" });
  }
};


Have you tried to print the variable email content on the server-side console?

Hello, try adding cors in the react section, also check that the postman and backend are working correctly, then make sure the cros settings are correct.
